# Is Cypress configuration cached?

Tags: configuration, cypress, end-to-end

It seems to me like Cypress configuration is cached, but I can't find this documented.

If I update `baseUrl` in *cypress.json*, it's not updating when I run my tests. Looking at the settings via the Cypress UI shows that this is the location being used for this var - but it's not picking up the latest values, even after restarting.

If it is cached, is there a way to reload the cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm that it isn't cached.

It turns out I had a cypress.json in the root, and one in /cypress subdirectory. The root one is the one that is loaded, and gets loaded every time.